# Angular universal has error at express and cannot run

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm trying to use Angular universal for my project but I facing some problem and below is detail

**1. ng --version**

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.2
Node: 13.5.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.0.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core               9.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics         9.0.2
@angular/cdk                       9.0.0
@angular/cli                       9.0.2
@angular/localize                  9.0.5
@angular/material                  9.0.0
@angular/material-moment-adapter   9.0.0
@angular/platform-server           9.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                   9.0.7
@nguniversal/builders              9.1.0
@nguniversal/common                9.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine        9.1.0
@schematics/angular                9.0.2
@schematics/update                 0.900.2
rxjs                               6.5.4
typescript                         3.7.5
webpack                            4.41.6
```

---

**2. npm run dev:ssr(server.ts has error in express function: "const server = express();")**

```
Hash: 31de884421a0ec6deaeb
Time: 39355ms
Built at: 05/02/2020 11:20:23 AM
      Asset      Size  Chunks         Chunk Names
    main.js  4.08 KiB    main         main
main.js.map   3.5 KiB    main  [dev]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js main.js.map
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 28 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in server.ts:13:18 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof e' has no call signatures.

13   const server = express();
                    ~~~~~~~
  server.ts:4:1
    4 import * as express from 'express';
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead.


chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 3.13 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 148 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 86.1 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.css, styles.css.map (styles) 438 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 9.61 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-05-02T04:20:45.807Z - Hash: 07ffd3421b26b0f8711d - Time: 53740ms
this.debug is not a function
```

---

**3. resolve error on express using "import express from 'express';" instead of "import * as express from 'express'"**

```
Date: 2020-05-02T04:25:47.562Z - Hash: 07ffd3421b26b0f8711d - Time: 90330ms
Compiled successfully.
D:\AngularProjects\helloj
obclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:19052
            window.addEventListener('test', (/** @type {?} */ (null)), Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
                   ^

TypeError: window.addEventListener is not a function
    at supportsPassiveEventListeners (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:19052:20)
    at normalizePassiveListenerOptions (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:19073:12)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/tooltip.js (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:153609:125)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Object../src/app/verified/history-recruitment/history-recruitment.component.ts (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:336514:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Object../src/app/app.routes.ts (D:\Ang
ularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:303743:41)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Object../src/app/shared/shared.module.ts (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:332543:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\AngularProjects\hellojobclient\dist\hellojobclient\server\main.js:20:30)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58315
```

After encountering this error I trying resolve by comment code follow tracking error but many more time faced to other errors

Comment: You cannot use browser objects like `window`, `navigatior` when you are rendering the website server side.

Comment: Thanks David, I know that, but I resolved that error, the reason for the error is ssr not supported material tooltip

Comment: Hi @NguyễnVănMạnh, could you please post a reference about this ?

Answer (score 3):

Go to `tsconfig.json` and remove this two lines or comment it and check;
and try to import JSON file using another methods

```
// "resolveJsonModule": true,
// "esModuleInterop": true
```

Comment: This helped me, thank you. I also had to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` as well to my tsconfig as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in the app() function in the server.ts file.
By default, it looks like this:

```
export function app(): void
```

And it should be like this:

```
export function app(): express.Express
```

There is no need to fix the import

Fixing the app() function helped me